# Interpolation in React is not working this way can anybody please help me in this regards?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying interpolation, this way

```
var sample = "test";
var result = 'this is just a ${sample}'; 
alert(result);
```

it's not working, it's just alerting as it is, this is just a ${sample}, can anybody please help me regarding this? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to use backticks instead of quotes (which are left of the `1` on your keyboard)

```
var result = `this is just a ${sample}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES5, it would be

```
var sample = "test";

var result = 'this is just a '+sample; 

alert(result);
```